# Unmarshalling Error

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2010, marshalling

I get an error whenever I try do a request to a SOAP service:

> Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.domain.com/ws/servicename/", local:"dummyArg"). Expected elements are <{}dummyArg>

The method that I'm calling has is defined as:

```
function GetTxServer(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): TxServer;
```

I have little experience with SOAP, and I couldn't find any useful information on this. Feel free to ask any question that might speed up the process in finding the issue.

I believe that the way that I am calling the function is not the correct way!

I'm using Delphi 2010, and I've called the method like so:

```
Response := GetTxServer.requestIVULoto(cm);
```

Comment: The code you say you used doesn't match the declaration of the method. The `GetTxServer` function takes three parameters, but you gave it zero. Also, what `requestIVULoto` and `cm`?

Comment: I think what he needs is something along the lines of: MyTxServer := GetTxServer(False, TheEndpointURL, TheRio);
Then he can call
Response := MyTxServer.requestIVULoto(cm);

Answer (score 1):

Use SoapUI (the free version is fine) to consume the WSDL and make sure that you can properly send a request to the server and get a response that makes sense.  Then make a "mock" service in SoapUI, to act as the server. Send your Delphi requests to the mockservice (typically done by setting your  endpoint to http://localhost:8089 or some such) so that you can inspect the XML that you're sending out.  Now you can experiment and determine whether the problem is due to sending out bad requests, the server returning bad/unexpected results, trouble interpreting good results, etc..

Aside from that, I'd guess that you're failing to allocate or populate "cm" correctly.  I assume that's your request object.

Also... big tip here....
Use the RIO_BeforeExecute event to debug this.  At that point, the SOAPRequest is a string that you can inspect or dump to a file. So you can see what you're sending, without having to use SoapUI, Fiddler2, Wireshark, etc..

Comment: I installed the SoapUI, I am populating the "cm" correctly the problem seems to be the xml, this is the wsdl, if its of any help: http://207.150.244.30:9000/txserver/1?wsdl';

Comment: Here is the wdsl if its of any help: http://207.150.244.30:9000/txserver/1?wsdl  and if any one can help?

Comment: cm is a transaction and requestIVULoto is the function.             TxServer = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{FA236F41-8840-15A4-8F74-1E1583384A66}']
    function  requestIVULoto(const transaction: transaction): ivuLotoData; stdcall;
    function  requestTxInfo(const arg0: txInfoRequest): txInfoResponse; stdcall;
  end;